# Install GeoIP on Windows?

Tags: python, django, geoip

Does anybody know how to install `GeoIP's C library` on `Windows` in a few simple steps. Even a few complicated steps will do. I researched and tried to compile it from the setup file but failed several times. Sometimes, I get errors saying that `GeoIP.h` could not be located. Other times I get that `bugtrack_url` is not a valid option for compilation.

I have tried using `pip install GeoIP` and I have also tried just using `setup.py`.

Has anyone had any luck setting this up on Windows?

Comment: You can get rid of the `bugtrack_url` complaint by removing that line from the `setup.py` file (which will be in the package under a folder named `build` if pip failed. As for the rest, good luck.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use them. The `windows` tag when used this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'GeoIP.h could not be located' error indicates that you need to install `libgeoip-dev` first. Though I have no idea how to install it on windows easiy.

I suggest you to use the [pygeoip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoip/) package, based on the following  reasons:

- pygeoip is a pure python package
- pygeoip supports Python 3
- pygeoip has wheel support
- pygeoip has better [documentation](http://pygeoip.readthedocs.org/en/)
- pygeoip has 50x more downloads on pypi.
- pygeoip is compatible with GeoIP's API

Comment: For the legacy GeoIP format, pygeoip is the better API unless you absolutely need the extra speed. It isn't quite compatible with the MaxMind API, but the differences are fairly minor.

Comment: For the new MaxMind format, [geoip2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2) provides both a C extension and pure Python version.

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. I was trying to use Django's GeoIP implementation, but this was far easier to work with and apply to what I needed.